# Did the Exosuit upgrade in the space stations get removed?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Prior to the new build update, whenever you visited a space station if you went to the door on the right (after you space ship rotates), there would always be an exosuit inventory slot upgrade.

Now, it seems a teleporter that takes you to your home base occupies its spot instead on all of the space stations.  Are all space stations this way now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the NEXT update, the exosuit upgrade in space stations have returned.  You can find the upgrade location in the spot where the exosuit components and blueprints shop is.  You can purchase the upgrade using units just like before.  You can also choose between a general, cargo, or technology inventory space.

The price of the upgrade will go up with each upgrade you buy at a space station, however the prices are different for each of the 3 types of upgrades.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed they have been removed. While looking at the official "Foundation's Update" and the 1.09 patch on the [No Man's Sky Patch Log](http://www.no-mans-sky.com/foundation-update/) page, I saw this:

- Suit upgrade pods are no longer spawned in stations

It's quite unfortunate, so I'm glad I grabbed a ton when I was first into the game at launch.

Comment: ...But, it's not a problem since the new `signal booster` can directly lead to a pod containing a suit upgrade.